# write query without using cursors

Tags: sql, cursor

I wrote this query to display single client's account transactions:

```
select *
from (
    select top 1 
       [id]
      ,[client_id]
      ,[transactionDate]
      ,N'revolving balance' [details]
      ,NULL [amount]
      ,NULL [debit]
      ,NULL [credit]
      ,[balance]
  FROM [dbo].[bsitems]
  where [client_id]=@client_id and
        [transactionDate] < @transactionDateFrom
        order by id desc) t1
        union
SELECT [id]
      ,[client_id]
      ,[transactionDate]
      ,[details]
      ,[amount]
      ,[debit]
      ,[credit]
      ,[balance]
  FROM [dbo].[bsitems]
  where [client_id]=@client_id and
        [transactionDate] between @transactionDateFrom and @transactionDateTo
```

How to display the transactions for all clients that exists in "client" table? Assume client table structure is (id, name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the second part (which is really what the transactions are), just use `join`:

```
SELECT b.id, b.client_id, b.transactionDate, b.details,
       b.amount, b.debit, b.credit, b.balance
FROM [dbo].[bsitems] b join
     clients c
     on b.client_id = c.client_id
WHERE transactionDate between @transactionDateFrom and @transactionDateTo;
```

This assumes that the `client_id` is stored in the `clients` table.

The first part of the query is returning the most recent id before the from date.  It returns no rows if there are no previous transactions.  You can approach this in a similar way.

```
select id, client_id, transactiondate, details, amount, debit, credit, balance
from (SELECT b.id, b.client_id, b.transactionDate,
             N'revolving balance' as b.details,
             NULL as b.amount, NULL as b.debit, NULL as b.credit,
             b.balance,
             row_number() over (partition by client_id order by TransactionDate desc) as seqnum
      FROM [dbo].[bsitems] b join
           clients c
           on b.client_id = c.client_id
      WHERE transactionDate < @transactionDateFrom
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Instead of `top 1` this is using `row_number()` to assign a sequential value to the transactions before the cutoff date.  Then the most recent of these is chosen.

The final result is just the `union all` of these two queries:

```
select id, client_id, transactiondate, details, amount, debit, credit, balance
from (SELECT b.id, b.client_id, b.transactionDate,
             N'revolving balance' as b.details,
             NULL as b.amount, NULL as b.debit, NULL as b.credit,
             b.balance,
             row_number() over (partition by client_id order by TransactionDate desc) as seqnum
      FROM [dbo].[bsitems] b join
           clients c
           on b.client_id = c.client_id
      WHERE transactionDate < @transactionDateFrom
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
union all
SELECT b.id, b.client_id, b.transactionDate, b.details,
       b.amount, b.debit, b.credit, b.balance
FROM [dbo].[bsitems] b join
     clients c
     on b.client_id = c.client_id
WHERE transactionDate between @transactionDateFrom and @transactionDateTo;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT TOP 1 
         [id]
        ,[client_id]
        ,[transactionDate]
        ,N'revolving balance' [details]
        ,NULL [amount]
        ,NULL [debit]
        ,NULL [credit]
        ,[balance]
    FROM [dbo].[bsitems]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[client] ON [dbo].[bsitems].[client_id] = [dbo].[client].[id]
    AND [transactionDate] < @transactionDateFrom
    ORDER BY id DESC
) t1

UNION

SELECT 
     [id]
    ,[client_id]
    ,[transactionDate]
    ,[details]
    ,[amount]
    ,[debit]
    ,[credit]
    ,[balance]
FROM [dbo].[bsitems]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[client] ON [dbo].[bsitems].[client_id] = [dbo].[client].[id]
AND [transactionDate] between @transactionDateFrom and @transactionDateTo
```